# how to add multiple values to a column in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

This is my query of creation of table

```
CREATE TABLE `result` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `l_id` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `lname` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `first_prize` varchar(9) DEFAULT NULL,
  `consolation_prize` varchar(9) DEFAULT NULL,
  `second_prize` varchar(9) DEFAULT NULL,
  `third_prize` varchar(9) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fourth_prize` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fifth_prize` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sixth_prize` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `seventh_prize` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `eigth_prize` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

and this is the query of insertion of values

```
INSERT INTO `result` (`id`, `l_id`, `lname`, `first_prize`, `consolation_prize`, `second_prize`, `third_prize`, `fourth_prize`, `fifth_prize`, `sixth_prize`, `seventh_prize`, `eigth_prize`) VALUES
(1, '1', 'Win-Win', 'WO-878475', 'WO-878474', 'WO-878477', 'WO-878455', 8474, 8477, 8412, 8473, 8689),
(2, '2', 'KARUNNYA', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 6, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL),
(3, '3', 'SOUBHAGYA', 'WE-878656', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL),
(4, '4', 'SREE SAKTHI', 'NB-750180', 'NE-750180', 'KO-594630', 'KF-678534', 6786, 4356, 2456, 4566, 7657);
```

the problem is, I cant insert multiple values to any of the columns such as first_prize,second_prize,third_prize etc...
How to do that ,please help me I have no idea and I am new to all these.

Comment: No idea what you're trying to achieve. You want to insert multiple values in the same column?

Comment: Seems to me you shouldn't do this. Columns are for single values for a given row. So either have more columns to house the other data (if different to each other) or more rows to house the same data for a different user or whatever. You can do it with delimiter or enum, but unless you really know the problems this causes you probably don't want to be doing it

Comment: Need bit more explanation on this, your question is not clear.

Comment: What Do you mean by 'I cant insert multiple values to any of the columns' .Columns contain single values.Learn the basics and re frame your question

Comment: i need to enter two different values(ie,WO-878475,WE-878475) in the column first_prize.

Comment: Is there any alternative method for doing like that??

Comment: Do any of the answers help you?

Answer (score 0):

INSERT INTO result (id, l_id, lname, first_prize, consolation_prize, second_prize, third_prize, fourth_prize, fifth_prize, sixth_prize, seventh_prize, eigth_prize)
VALUES (1, '1', 'Win-Win', 'WO-878475,WO-878474,WO-878477', NULL,NULL, 'WO-878455', 8474, 8477, 8412, 8473, 8689);

increase the length of column.

Comment: Increase the length of the column to what? This is one of the many problems with shoehorning multiple values into one field. You don't know what data you have. Should it be varchar(50)? Or should we make it 250 "just in case"?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use "2", the last option in my answer.

> i need to enter two different values(ie,WO-878475,WE-878475) in the column first_prize

To answer your question directly, you can have a delimiter between values (eg | or comma) and then when you select the field data you split based on your delimiter. This is 99% of the time a bad design approach, it really is.

I sincerely suggest that you instead consider a slight re-design and do either:
**1)**
Add more fields, such as `first_prize_1` and `first_prize_2`. This is likely not the best way but I don't know all of your setup - this will make maintenance problems if you need another in the future, such as `first_prize_3`, but a lot better than multiple values in a single field.

**2)**
This is likely the better way - Make a new table `prizes` and have the fields:

```
id  
prize_id  
prize_level (this will be 1, 2, 3 etc for first prize and so on)  
competition_id
```

Then just have a row per prize per competition, and select everything for the competition_id, and the fields allow you to state what prize it is, etc.

So `id` field is auto increment for unique row ID. Then rows would look like:
`id` = 1; `prize_id` = WO-878475; `prize_level` = 1; `competition_id` = 1;
`id` = 2; `prize_id` = WE-878475; `prize_level` = 1; `competition_id` = 1;

Then you select where `competition_id` = 1 and you get all the possible prizes for that competition, with the prize_id and prize_levels (1st, 2nd etc). This way, as per the above example, you can have more than one first prize, and as rows are endless you can have as many or as little prizes as you require per competition and thus are not restricted by the fields you have in a table (like field `first_prize`, `second_prize` etc).

Comment: please explain the 2nd method some more elaborately.

Comment: I've updated my answer to add more info how it would work. If you need something specific let me know

Answer (score 0):

MySQL is a relational database. I suggest you to use two tables.
The first one `event` will contain the event data (`id` and `name`, etc.), the second one can be structured as following:

```
  `event_id` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `winner` varchar(9) NOT NULL,
  `prize_type` int(11) NOT NULL,
```

Then you can define your keys, e.g.:

```
0 = consolation prize
1 = first prize
2 = second prize
etc..
```